# Conditional adding flags in Excel

Tags: excel

I have the following data in excel

**Data**

```
Date      Title Released
1-1-2017  No
2-1-2017  No
3-1-2017  Yes
4-1-2017  Yes
5-1-2017  No
6-1-2017  No
7-1-2017  No
8-1-2017  No
9-1-2017  Yes
10-1-2017 No
11-1-2017 No
12-1-2017 No 
13-1-2017 No
```

**Problem:**

I want to add a flag column which is 1 if a title was released on that date or if a title was released within 3 days from that date

The solution needs to be formula based because the number of days since release condition can change

Thanks in advance

**Expected Output**

```
Date      Title Released  Flag
1-1-2017  No              0  
2-1-2017  No              0
3-1-2017  Yes             1
4-1-2017  Yes             1
5-1-2017  No              1 
6-1-2017  No              1 
7-1-2017  No              1
8-1-2017  No              0
9-1-2017  Yes             1 
10-1-2017 No              1
11-1-2017 No              1
12-1-2017 No              1
13-1-2017 No              0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data starts in cell A1 and the Title Release (Yes/No) data is in column B and each day only has one row:

I would copy the following formula into cell C5:

```
=IF(OR(B5="Yes",B4="Yes",B3="Yes",B2="Yes"),1,0)
```

The formula doesn't work for cells C2 through C4 because it's referencing cells outside of the data; that can be fixed by deleting the inappropriate references inside the OR statement.

Comment: Your formula works, but the OP only wants to look back 3 days.

Comment: Simple, although as DeanOC mentioned I wanted for 3 days, your logic works!! Thanks a lot!